# Disable dates that aren't available for uib-datepicker-popup

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am utilizing uib-datepicker-popup and want to only enable the dates that are available for that specific location.  For example, if someone choose the DC location, I want to only enable the dates available at the DC location and disable all other dates so users cannot select it.  If DC only has availability on April 13, 20, 25, and 31, I want all the other dates to be disabled.  Is there a way to do this using AngularJS and this directive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Jeff, `angular UI date picker` has `dateDisabled` option to specify which date has to be disabled. You can specify the method inside `date-options` like this

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
      dateDisabled: function(data) {
        var date = data.date,
          mode = data.mode;
        return mode === 'day' && !$scope.IsDateAvailable(date);
      }
    };
```

A working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gilango/gbe5mb9r/) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation, uib-datepicker-popup is a wrapper for uib-datepicker, and supports the same options. You would provide a function via the dateDisabled option, and this function would take a parameter object `{date: date, mode: mode}` and would return true/false to indicate if the date should be disabled.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker